# Remover tudo depois da segunda ocorrência de uma vírgula

Tags: r, regex

Eu tenho uma df com endereços e quero remover tudo que está depois da segunda vírgula.

```
exemplo <- c("Rua Pajé, 30, apto 44", "Av. Brasil,55, blocoB")
```

O que eu já tentei:

```
gsub(",[^,]+,(.*)", "", exemplo)
[1] "Rua Pajé"   "Av. Brasil"
```

Mas o que eu quero é:

```
"Rua Pajé, 30", "Av. Brasil,55"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma alternativa é:

```
exemplo <- c("Rua Pajé, 30, apto 44", "Av. Brasil,55, blocoB")

gsub("^([^,]+,[^,]+),.*$", "\\1", exemplo)
```

Eu uso os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que são respectivamente o início e fim da string.

Depois eu uso `[^,]+` ([um ou mais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) caracteres [que não sejam](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) a vírgula), seguido de vírgula, seguido por mais caracteres que não sejam a vírgula. E coloco tudo isso dentro de parênteses [para formar um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Depois temos a segunda vírgula, seguido de `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres), até o final da string (`$`).

No parâmetro de substituição eu uso `\\1`, que corresponde ao que foi capturado pelos parênteses (no caso, tudo até antes da segunda da vírgula). Como é o primeiro par de parênteses, então eles correspondem ao primeiro grupo de captura, daí o número 1 
 em `"\\1"`. E como dentro desses parênteses tem tudo até antes da segunda vírgula, então `\\1` é exatamente o trecho que você quer. O resultado é:

```
[1] "Rua Pajé, 30"  "Av. Brasil,55"
```

[Veja rodando no Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/TMst7Y).

Answer (score 4):

Aqui vai.

```
sub("(^[^,]*,[^,]*),.*$", "\\1", exemplo)
#[1] "Rua Pajé, 30"  "Av. Brasil,55"
```

Explicação.

1. `[^,]` corresponde a qualquer caráter exceto a vírgula. O circunflexo como primeiro caráter dentro dos parêntesis retos nega a classe que se segue.
2. `[^,]*` qualquer caráter exceto a vírgula repetido zero ou mais vezes.
3. `^[^,]*` no princípio da string.
4. `(^[^,]*,[^,]*)` o padrão `^[^,]*` é seguido de uma vírgula e depois de `^[^,]*`, explicado acima. Isto está dentro de `()` para formar um grupo.
5. `(^[^,]*,[^,]*),.*$` o grupo definido acima é seguido de uma vírgula e de um número qualquer de quaisquer carateres até ao fim da string.